# Prove the mod 2 Steenrod algebra has counit

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

**Edit:** *$\epsilon$ must send $Sq^i$ to $0$ since it is the case where $\mathcal{A}_2$ is a graded algebra. The Wikipedia page presents the answer itself.*

I'm trying to show that the mod $2$ Steenrod algebra $\mathcal{A}_2$ is a Hopf algebra. Here we need to define a counit $\epsilon: \mathcal{A}_2\to \mathbb{Z}_2$ which is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-algebra homomorphism. In [Steenrod-Epstein](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/steenrod-epstein.pdf), they suggest me to define $\epsilon$ as an [augmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmentation_(algebra)), that is $\epsilon$ takes each $Sq^i$ to $1$. My attempt is as follows.

Let $\underline{\mathcal{A}}$ be the free associative algebra generated by the $Sq^i$, then $\mathcal{A}_2$ is the quotient of $\underline{\mathcal{A}}$ by the Adem relations. We can easily define $\underline{\epsilon}:\underline{\mathcal{A}}\to \mathbb{Z}_2$ such that $\underline{\epsilon}(Sq^i)=1$ for all $i$. Hence we need $\underline{\epsilon}$ be equivalent on both side of the Adem relations. In other words, with $a<2b$ we have the following identity on $\mathbb{Z}_2$:
$$1=\underline{\epsilon}(Sq^a Sq^b)=\underline{\epsilon}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor a/2\rfloor}\binom{b-i-1}{a-2i} Sq^{a+b-i} Sq^i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor a/2\rfloor}\binom{b-i-1}{a-2i}.$$
I think a number-theoretic approach would be complicated. So I come up with the following argument. Let $P=\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$ then $H^*(P)=\mathbb{Z}_2[u]$ with $\dim u=1$. I wonder if there is some $k$ such that $Sq^{a+b-i} Sq^i(u^k)\neq 0$ for all $i$? If that is true, then $Sq^{a+b-i} Sq^i(u^k)=u^{k+a+b}\ \forall i$, and our desired equation would be obvious. In case my argument won't success, I'd like to know how the actual proof look like *(even number-theoretic ones)*. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\epsilon$ should send each $Sq^i$ to $0$, not to $1$.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't read the wikipedia entry carefully. I will edit the question. If you bother to give an answer then I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counit map is defined by sending each $Sq^i$ with $i>0$ to zero. As the wikipedia page you cite mentions, this is an example of an augmentation on a graded ring, since the degree of $Sq^i$ is $i$, and sending positive degree elements to zero is a way to define an augmentation.